# API Design Dilemma: Opaque Handles

Tags: c, api-design

I'm in the process of designing a library that tries to unify the platform specific details under a single generic handle (1), or a set thereof (2).

To make the question more concrete, I'll provide excerpts of the two implementations and a sample usage.

(1) Tagged union; a catch-it-all type:

```
enum tb_handle_kind {};

/* These two are never exposed to the user: */
struct tb_dir {
    struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW find_data;
    HANDLE search_handle;
};

struct tb_file {
    HANDLE native_handle;
};

struct tb_handle {
    enum tb_handle_kind kind;

    union {
        struct tb_file file;
        struct tb_dir dir;
    };
};
```

Which you would use in the following way:

```
file_open(struct tb_handle *, const char *);
handle_close(struct tb_handle *);

struct tb_handle file;
file_open(&file, "path/to/file");

...

handle_close(&file); /* No need for a cast, or a file-specfic function. */
```

(2) Generic handle as the base class for others:

```
struct tb_handle {
    /* Fields shared by each handle. */
};

struct tb_dir {
    struct tb_handle base; /* Now a "base class" of tb_dir. */
    struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW find_data;
    HANDLE search_handle;
};
```

Usage:

```
/* Either a pair of init/close functions. */
int dir_open(struct tb_dir *, const char *);
int dir_close(struct tb_dir *);

/* Or handle_close from the previous example, that now requires a cast: */
handle_close((struct tb_handle *) &some_dir);
```

As far I can tell, (1) offers an easier API to use at the expense of type safety whereas (2) makes for more mental gymnastics with improved safety (you can't pass a handle of the wrong kind to a function).

Which one would you rather use from the perspective of the user?

Comment: Does the user need to see _any_ of the fields of the handle at all? If not, I would opt for a `void*` handle.

Comment: If the handle is supposed to be opaque, then only the first of the two alternatives really fits the bill.  To the extent that the user has to worry about different handle types, you no longer have opacity.